# change password in ejabberd using php script

Tags: php, ejabberd

Is that any possible way to change user password in ejabberd 
I have tried using below xml but its not working for me

Tried :

```
<iq type='set' id='fabiang_xmpp_57e51e6c39d4d' from='admin@192.168.1.73'>
  <query xmlns='jabber:iq:register'>
    <username>test</username>
    <password>newpass</password>
</query>
</iq>
```

Result :

```
{xmlcdata,<<"User already exists">>}
```

Tried :

```
<iq type='set' id='fabiang_xmpp_57e51e6c39d4d'>
      <query xmlns='jabber:iq:register:changepassword'>
       <old_password>test</old_password>
       <username>87906</username>
       <password>google</password>
      </query>
</iq>
```

Result :

```
{xmlcdata,<<"No module is handling this query">>}
```

FYI : Error/Result i catch from ejabberd.log

Any thoughts, Any helps

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your first stanza is fine, except that you're trying to change password of a different user (you're logged in as *admin* and changing password for *test*). I wouldn't expect that to work.

This should work fine:

```
<iq type='set' id='fabiang_xmpp_57e51e6c39d4d' from='admin@192.168.1.73'>
  <query xmlns='jabber:iq:register'>
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>newpass</password>
</query>
</iq>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,
Your solution is not working its throwing error like :   get_entity_affiliations

Answer (score 0):

For PHP, You can try this

```
public function changePassword($user, $host, $new_password) 
{
    @exec('sudo ejabberdctl change-password '.$user.' '.$host.' '.$new_password.' 2>&1', $output, $status);
    return $output;       
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but i am not looking for command i need solution in which i can do it via other ways